# ReadFromKafka stuck in beam process with Dataflow

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am trying to read from a kafka topic using Apache Beam and Dataflow, print the data to the console and finally write them to a pubsub topic. But it seems to get stuck in the ReadFromKafka function. There are many data written into the kafka topic, but nothing happen in this pipeline when it runs.

```
import apache_beam as beam
import argparse

from apache_beam.io.kafka import ReadFromKafka
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions

def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
pipeline_args.extend([
    '--runner=DataflowRunner',
    '--project=sample-project',
    '--region=xxx',
    '--staging_location=gs://xxx',
    '--temp_location=gs://xxx',
    '--job_name=beam-streaming',
    '--worker_machine_type=n1-standard-16',
    '--num_workers=1',
    '--streaming'
])      

class PrintValue(beam.DoFn):
        def process(self, element):
            print(element)
            return [element]

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
    _ = (
        pipeline
        | 'Read from Kafka' >> ReadFromKafka( 
            consumer_config={'bootstrap.servers': 'ip:port' },
            topics=['local-events'])
        | 'print' >> beam.ParDo(PrintValue())
        | 'write to pubsub' >> beam.io.WriteToPubSub('projects/sample/topics/test')
        )



if __name__ == '__main__':
 run()
```

I know there is an Issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-11998
but as i understand it, this problem only belongs to portable runners. Does anybody know if ReadFromKafka is working with unbounded data in **Dataflow**?

- Python 3.8.10
- apache-beam==2.29.0
- kafka-python==2.0.2

Comment: where you able to find a resolution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and switched to using a `beam.Map` transform instead (make sure your `printValue` function is defined within the run function, or you have a [proper dependency management method](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/)):

```
| Map(lambda value: printValue(value))
```

Note that the type of elements you get from `ReadFromKafka` is an ad hoc class named BeamSchema_xxxxxxxxx, having the following attributes (assuming you configure reader `with_metadata=True`): 'topic', 'value', 'count', 'headers', 'index', 'key', 'offset', 'partition', 'timestamp', 'timestampTypeId', 'timestampTypeName'. It does't `print` nice if at all.
So you want to decode your values first, for example:

```
def decode_kafka_message(record) -> str:
"""
Record attributes passed from ReadFromKafka transform:  'topic', 'value'
    'count', 'headers', 'index', 'key', 'offset', 'partition',
    'timestamp', 'timestampTypeId', 'timestampTypeName'.


:return: Message value as string
"""
if hasattr(record, 'value'):
    value = record.value
elif isinstance(record, tuple):
    value = record[1]
else:
    raise RuntimeError('unknown record type: %s' % type(record))

return value.decode("UTF-8") if isinstance(value, bytes) else value
```

That connector could use some work and better docs.